# how to filter by tags in Mailgun API

Tags: php, mailgun

So i want to filter by tags in query string like this :

```
$queryString = array(
        'begin'        => $begin,
        'ascending'    => 'yes',
        'pretty'       => 'yes',
        'tags'        => 'my tag'
);
```

but i got this error **The parameters passed to the API were invalid. Check your inputs!**, so i changed like this `'tags' => ['my tag']` , but i still got the same error,

so please if someone has any idea i will be very appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's supported any longer, or it is broken. I also tried several notations.

Comment: It appears that tags with a space character in them are not queryable using the events API, or at least not over PHP. Removing the space solved my problem. I informed the company.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 11.08.2021:**
In the meantime, I have implemented the tag as described below **and it works**.
Further, I have an official feedback from MailGun, **that tags over the API don't have to contain spaces**.

Unbelievable, but it seems as  Sven P is still right with his comment (after about 5 Years).
I'm on the way to implement a query interface to the MailGun log (with vb.net).
First I have set a tag with a readable text by sending an email over the API with:

```
request.AddParameter("o:tag", "Word and another word")
```

and tried to get all log entries by query the MG log with:

```
request.AddParameter("tags", "Word and another word")
```

And get **no items** back from the log, although I can see that the tag **is** stored in the MG log and I also can set a filter to the tag in the MG log (portal).

After I have changed the text (sending) to:

```
request.AddParameter("o:tag", "VersandKey1")
```

and (query log) to:

```
request.AddParameter("tags", "VersandKey1")
```

**It seems to work now.**

**So it seems as the API don't work as soon as there are spaces in the tag.**